# Howto clear a textfile without deleting file?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Question: I have an ini file which I need to clear before I add info to it.

Unfortunately, if I just delete the file, the permissions are gone as well.

Is there a way to delete a file's content without deleting the file ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
String path = "c:/file.ini";

using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Truncate))
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        writer.Write("data");
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this approach is best for you to use if you have all the code for writing the new content inside the same method. If you have the deleting functionality and the writing of the new content in separate methods, you should use any of the other answers instead.

Comment: Why would you use this instead of "using (var writer = File.CreateText(path)) { writer.Write("data"); }"?

Comment: In your case if file doesn't exist it is created. We don't know if it is valid for topic-starter. I used general example that can be adapted appropriately.

Comment: Actually, using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream)) already clears the file.

Answer (score 5):

Just open the file in truncate (i.e. non-append) mode and close it. Then its contents are gone. Or use the shortcut in the `My` namespace:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("filename", "", False)
```

Comment: if he is going to be adding new data to in anywho, why not just write to the file in truncate mode? "I have an ini file which I need to clear before I add info to it." - OP

Comment: @Adkins: only the OP can answer this. That he asked the question suggests that he’s using an API to write the INI file which uses append mode internally – weird, admittedly.

Comment: Good comment from **Adkins**. If you want to do it all in one go (just overwrite the content with new directly), see [QrystaL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957709/howto-clear-a-textfile-without-deleting-file/3957790#3957790)s answer for a good approach.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not 100% sure, but you can try this:

```
File.WriteAllText( filename, "");
```

I'm not sure if this will delete, and recreate the file (in that case your permission problem will persist, or if it will clean out the file. Try it!

Answer (score 3):

This should probably work:

```
using (File.Create("your filename"));
```

Here, the using does not have a block because of the ; at the end of the line. The File.Create truncates the file itself, and the using closes it immediately.